# -ON INPUT- change <textarea> background color (bootstrap)

Tags: bootstrap-4, textarea, background-color, form-control

`textarea.form-control {
    background-color: #63AEEB
}`

and

```
<div class="col-sm-6"><textarea class="w-100 mb-n2 form-control"></textarea></div>
```

Turns the background blue before user enters anything into it. No good. I want white, then user enters, then change background color. But how, batman? <3

Answer (score 0):

Took a while, but I found an old question that has a great answer.

[PHP Change background color, based on correct or incorrect answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28355240/php-change-background-color-based-on-correct-or-incorrect-answer)

p.s. go ahead and put your java in a new < script >, then you can copypasta everything